# Run Celery beat and worker concurrently in FLASK app

Tags: python, flask, celery, celerybeat

I am working on a FLASK app with Celery. In it, I run the app using the line `app.run()`. If I change it to the following

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

application = current_app._get_current_object()

worker = worker.worker(app=application)
beat = beat.beat(app=application)

options = {
    'broker': app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
    'loglevel': 'INFO',
    'traceback': True,
}

worker.run(**options)
beat.run(**options)
app.run()
```

This runs the app and the worker, but the Celery beat does not run until I shut down the worker. Is there any way that I can run both concurrently? Maybe add the `-B` flag to the options settings somehow? I'd appreciate any help on the matter.

Answer (score 3):

If you add 'beat' = True to your options, when you call worker.run(**options) it'll give the beat task to a worker:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

application = current_app._get_current_object()

worker = worker.worker(app=application)

options = {
    'broker': app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
    'loglevel': 'INFO',
    'traceback': True,
    'beat': True,
}

worker.run(**options)
app.run()
```

It should stop the beat when the worker stops.